# How to display data in various rows to a column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a sample table which looks like this

```
create table test (
uname   varchar2(20),
seq     number,
sub_id  number,
sub_val varchar2(20)
);

insert into test values ('a1',1,1,'t1');
insert into test values ('a1',1,2,'t2');
insert into test values ('a1',1,3,'t3');

insert into test values ('a1',2,1,'t4');
insert into test values ('a1',2,2,'t5');
insert into test values ('a1',2,3,'t6');

insert into test values ('b1',1,1,'t7');
insert into test values ('b1',1,2,'t8');

insert into test values ('b1',2,1,'t9');
insert into test values ('b1',2,3,'t10');

select * from test;
```

I would like to display that data in below format in Oracle SQL. Is that possible with SQL query?
(Basically all sub_ids for uname+seq combination should come in 1 column. So ColA will have data for sub_id = 1, ColB will have data for sub_id = 2 and so on for any uname+seq combination).

[image]

Comment: Read up on PIVOT

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select uname, seq,
       max(case when sub_id = 1 then sub_val end) as a,
       max(case when sub_id = 2 then sub_val end) as b,
       max(case when sub_id = 3 then sub_val end) as c
from test
group by uname, seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PIVOT` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT UNAME, SEQ,SUB_ID,SUB_VAL FRO TEST)
PIVOT
(MAX(SUB_VAL) FOR SUB_ID IN (1 AS A,2 AS B, 3 AS C))
```